# Firefox addon bar

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

The latest update of firefox (29) removed the add-on bar, i was working on an extension where i am using it like it is shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_add-on_bar)

```
var mediator = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var doc = mediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").document;
var addonBar = doc.getElementById("addon-bar");
```

so as a workaround i installed **The Addon Bar (Restored)** which gives back the addon bar, but i dont know how to add elements to it dynamically using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CustomizeableUI.jsm`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/03/06/australis-for-add-on-developers-2/

```
Cu.import("resource:///modules/CustomizableUI.jsm");
CustomizableUI.createWidget(
  { id : "aus-hello-button",
    defaultArea : CustomizableUI.AREA_NAVBAR,
    label : "Hello Button",
    tooltiptext : "Hello!",
    onCommand : function(aEvent) {
      let win = aEvent.target.ownerDocument.defaultView;

      win.alert("Hello!");
    }
  });
```

To make it add to the addonbar you have to create a new default area and set it to the addon bar.
Do this by functions `registerToolbarNode()` `registerArea()` some combo between those info is on the doc page above. Share how you do it man Im interested as well.